# React render ignore external variable but work fine with internal variable

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Possible some thing another wrong, but this is worked:

```
class NavMaster extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var mytag = ( <Item></Item> );
    return (
      <mytag/>
    )
  }
};
```

This show nothing:

```
var mytag = ( <Item></Item> );

class NavMaster extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <mytag/>
    )
  }
};
```

I'd like to use `mytag` in different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I  found the answer. Item must be defined before for external variables but for class it is possible to define after them.

```
class Item extends React.Component {}

var mytag = ( <Item></Item> );

class NavMaster extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <mytag/>
    )
  }
};

class Item extends React.Component {} // this is wrong - move up
```